# Get test error in a logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, predict

I'm performing some experiments with logistic regression in R with the `Auto` dataset included in R.

I've get the training part (80%) and the test part (20%) normalizing each part individually.

I can create the model without any problem with the line:

```
mlr<-glm(mpg ~ 
displacement + horsepower + weight, data =train)
```

I can even predict `train$mpg` with the train set:

```
trainpred<-predict(mlr,train,type="response")
```

And with this calculate the sample error:

```
etab <- table(trainpred, train[,1])
insampleerror<-sum(diag(etab))/sum(etab)
```

The problem comes when I want predict with the test set. I use the following line:

```
testpred<-predict(model_rl,test,type="response")
```

Which gives me this warning:

> 'newdata' had 79 rows but variables found have 313 rows

but it doesn't work, because `testpred` have the same length of `trainpred` (should be less). When I want calculate the error in test using `testpred` with the following line:

```
etabtest <- table(testpred, test[,1])
```

I get the following error:

> Error en table(testpred, test[, 1]) :
>           all arguments must have the same length

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One thing that probably won't make a difference: change you regression to `mlr<-glm(mpg ~ displacement + horsepower + weight, data =train)`. You don't need the `train$` if you have specified the data argument. More importantly, you might check that this creates a logistic regression. I think it is actually OLS. You have to set the link and family arguments. There are many examples on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I response my own question if someone have the same problem:

When I put the arguments in `glm` I'm saying what I want to predict, this is Auto$mpg labels with `train` data, hence, my `glm` call must be:

```
attach(Auto)
mlr<-glm(mpg ~ 
displacement + horsepower + weight, data=Auto, subset=indexes_train)
```

If now I call `predict`, `table`, etc there isn't any problem of structures sizes. Modifying this mistake it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As imo says:
"More importantly, you might check that this creates a logistic regression. I think it is actually OLS. You have to set the link and family arguments."

set familiy = 'binomial'